# Memcache PHP - run as a plugin

Tags: php, memcached

is it possible to run memcache for PHP not like a part of PHP server but like a part of my application? For example - I put the memcache files to my application includes folder and then run it from the application code? Like this:

```
<?php
include 'memcache.php';
$cache = new Memcache;
?>
```

Comment: Too bad, is there any other cache engine that can be included like I want? Or maybe I should do it in old-fashion way? By the $_SESSION or defined variables?

Comment: You could use an in-memory database table, but you'd be rolling your own cache handler that way. Session variables are per-user, so it all depends on what you want to cache really.